# issue with getting access to part of URL with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

im getting issue to access the URL display in the display_table_content.php, to display data into my table content.
It works find if I use the php alone without the jquery and ajax.

display_table_content.php

```
<input type="hidden" name="job_operation" id="job_operation1" value=""/>
<div id="post_details_data" class="tb_body_container"> </div>

url:display_table_content.php?jobs_name=www
```

JQUERY _ AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    fetch_user_data();

    function fetch_user_data() {

        var job_operation = "fetch";

        $.ajax({
            url:"get_table_content.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{job_operation:job_operation},
            success:function(data) {
                $('#post_details_data').html(data);
                $('#tb_jobs').DataTable({
                    dom: 'lBfrtip',
                    responsive: true,
                    "processing":true,
                    buttons:[{
                        extend: 'csv',
                        exportOptions: {columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
                    },
                        {
                            extend: 'pdf',
                            exportOptions: {columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'excel',
                            exportOptions: {columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'print',
                            exportOptions: {columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
                        }],
                    "order":[],
                    "columnDefs":[{"targets":[0, 3, 4],"orderable":false}]
                });
            }
        });

    }

});
```

get_table_content.php

```
if(isset($_POST["job_operation"])) {

require_once("database.php");
$pdo = pdo_con();

if ($_POST["job_operation"] == "fetch") {

$user_name= $_GET['jobs_name']; <-- Error seems to be from here

    $fetch_data = "SELECT * FROM jobs j WHERE jobs_name = $user_name";

    $result_User = $pdo->prepare($fetch_data);
    $result_User->execute();

    $output = '<table id="tb_jobs" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-responsive-lg" >

    <thead class="thead-dark">

    <tr>
        <th width="60%">Job Details</th>
        <th width="15%">Company Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>';

    $output .= '<tbody>';

    while ($row = $result_User->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $name_text1= $row['aaa'];
        $name_text2= $row['ddd'];

        $output .= '
    <tr>
        <td>' .$name_text1. '</td>
        <td>' .$name_text2. '</td>

    </tr>';
    }

    $output .= '</tbody></table>';

    echo $output;

}
```

}

i only the table header are being display, I cannnot fetch the table content due to the 'get' part in the get_table_content.php PHP page

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood waht you want :
This line seems having no sense : $user_name= filter_input(INPUT_GET,"www",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); <-- Error seems to be from here

Add in display_table_content.php :

```
 <input type="text" id="job_operation1" value=""/>
 <input type="text" id="user_name" value=""/>
 <script>
var jobrequest = new Object;
jobrequest.job_operation = $('#job_operation1').val();
jobrequest.user_name = $('#user_name').val();

$.ajax({
        url:"get_table_content.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:jobrequest,
```

In get_table_content.php :

```
$job_operation = $_POST["job_operation"];
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
```

Comment: the username are values that i fetch from a previous event `url:display_table_content.php?jobs_name=www`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you create a HTML table  in your back end with php, and then you use DataTables to work with this table you have created, first of all DataTables can use an ajax request to get the content from a json array created in your back end, saying that I think you should do it that way since is more easy to manage for future changes, also it will let the table creation to the front end which is the best aproach, saying that I let you an example to get your table in that way:

Your Html:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="userToFind" id="userToFind" value=""/>
   <br>
   <button id="btnSearch">Search Operations</button>
   <br>
    <div class="table-responsive" id="tableOperators" >
              <h2>Table Operators</h2>

             <table class="display dataTable" id="TablejobOperation"  >
               <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Operation</th>
                        <th>starts</th>
                        <th>ends</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Operation</th>
                        <th>starts</th>
                        <th>ends</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
              </table>

           </div>
            <br>

       </div>
```

your php:

```
     if ($_POST["action"] == "SLC" && isset($_POST["user_name"])) {
         $user_name= $_POST["user_name"];
         $query = "SELECT * FROM jobs j WHERE jobs_name = $user_name";
         $command= $conn->prepare($query);
         $command->execute();
         $result= $command->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         echo json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }
```

the DataTable javascript:

```
  var jobOperation= $('#TablejobOperation').DataTable({
                           "destroy": true,
                           "responsive":{
                             "details": {
                             renderer: function ( api, rowIdx, columns ) {
                               var data = $.map( columns, function ( col, i ) {
                                 return col.hidden ?
                                   '<tr data-dt-row="'+col.rowIndex+'" data-dt-column="'+col.columnIndex+'">'+
                                     '<td>'+col.title+':'+'</td> '+
                                     '<td>'+col.data+'</td>'+
                                   '</tr>' :
                                   '';
                               } ).join('');

                               return data ?$('<table/>').append( data ) :false;
                             }
                           }
                         },
                           "autoWidth": false,
                                 "ajax": {
                                     "url": 'some.php',
                                     "method": 'POST',
                                     data:{action:"SLC", user_name:username }
                                 },
                                 "columns": [
                                     {"data": "id"},
                                     {"data": "job_operation"},
                                     {"data": "type"},
                                     {"data": "starts"},
                                     {"data": "ends"}
                                 ],
                                 "language":{"url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"},
                                   "columnDefs": [
                                     {
                                       "className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"
                                      }
                                   ]
                             });
```

Your table goes inside a click event:

```
 $("#btnSearch").on('click',function(){
    var username = $.trim($('#userToFind').val().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
    var TablejobOperation = $('#tablaSeguros').DataTable();

   if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#TablejobOperation")) {
    TablejobOperation.destroy();
    $('#TablejobOperationtbody').remove();
     }
     //the datatable script from the top goes here
    })
```

Hope it helps